# CakePhp Generating a XML file from a string

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

Im trying to generate a XML file to be send through a invoice I´m generating. The XML I have in a string is the next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:implocal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/implocal/implocal.xsd" version="3.2" serie="Z" folio="155" fecha="2015-04-06T15:26:14" subTotal="1.00" total="1.32" certificado="" noCertificado="" TipoCambio="1" Moneda="MXN" metodoDePago="no aplica" sello="" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" formaDePago="no aplica" LugarExpedicion="no aplica">
    <cfdi:Emisor rfc="ZFL080519LG0" nombre="XXXX XXXXXXXX S.A. DE C.V.">
        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="XXX XXX XXXX" noExterior="XXXX" noInterior="B" colonia="XXXXXXX" localidad="Puebla" municipio="XXXXX" estado="Puebla" pais="México Teléfono 00000000" codigoPostal="XXXXXX" />
        <cfdi:ExpedidoEn pais="México" />
        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="Persona Moral del Regimen General" />
    </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="GOMAXXXXXXM50" nombre="XXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXX">
        <cfdi:Domicilio calle="XXXXX" noExterior="1" noInterior="O" colonia="XX XXXX" localidad="XXXXX" municipio="XXXXX" estado="XXXXX" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="00000" />
    </cfdi:Receptor>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1" unidad="NO APLICA" descripcion="NO APLICA" valorUnitario="1.00" importe="1.00" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="0.16">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00" importe="0.16" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <implocal:ImpuestosLocales version="1.0" TotaldeRetenciones="0.00" TotaldeTraslados="0.16">
            <implocal:TrasladosLocales ImpLocTrasladado="TRASLADADO" Importe="0.16" TasadeTraslado="16.00" />
        </implocal:ImpuestosLocales>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Im using CakePhp `Xml::Build($string);` to generate a XML, but for some reason not all the variables are going through. Im guessing the Xml is not being build or something. This is the code to generate the XML.

```
$XMLString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:implocal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/implocal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/implocal/implocal.xsd" version="3.2" serie="Z" folio="155" fecha="2015-04-06T15:26:14" subTotal="1.00" total="1.32" certificado="" noCertificado="" TipoCambio="1" Moneda="MXN" metodoDePago="no aplica" sello="" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" formaDePago="no aplica" LugarExpedicion="no aplica"><cfdi:Emisor rfc="XXXXXXX" nombre="XXXXX XXXXXX S.A. DE C.V."><cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="XXXX XXX XXX" noExterior="XXXXX" noInterior="X" colonia="XXXXXXXX" localidad="XXXX" municipio="XXXXX" estado="XXXXXX" pais="México Teléfono 00000000" codigoPostal="XXXXX" /><cfdi:ExpedidoEn pais="México" /><cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="Persona Moral del Regimen General" /></cfdi:Emisor><cfdi:Receptor rfc="XXXXXXXXXX" nombre="XXXX XXXXX XXXX"><cfdi:Domicilio calle="XXXX" noExterior="1" noInterior="O" colonia="XX XXX" localidad="XXXXX" municipio="XXXXX" estado="XXXX" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="00000" /></cfdi:Receptor><cfdi:Conceptos><cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1" unidad="NO APLICA" descripcion="NO APLICA" valorUnitario="1.00" importe="1.00" /></cfdi:Conceptos><cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="0.16"><cfdi:Traslados><cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00" importe="0.16" /></cfdi:Traslados></cfdi:Impuestos><cfdi:Complemento><implocal:ImpuestosLocales version="1.0" TotaldeRetenciones="0.00" TotaldeTraslados="0.16"><implocal:TrasladosLocales ImpLocTrasladado="TRASLADADO" Importe="0.16" TasadeTraslado="16.00" /></implocal:ImpuestosLocales></cfdi:Complemento></cfdi:Comprobante>';
$document=Xml::build($XMLString, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'return' => 'simplexml'));
```

What Im getting back when I check the variable that is being received with the element inspector on google chrome is the next.

```
documnet: Object
@attributes: Object
LugarExpedicion: "no aplica"
Moneda: "MXN"
TipoCambio: "1"
certificado: ""
fecha: "2015-04-06T15:26:14"
folio: "155"
formaDePago: "no aplica"
metodoDePago: "no aplica"
noCertificado: ""
sello: ""
serie: "Z"
subTotal: "1.00"
tipoDeComprobante: "ingreso"
total: "1.32"
version: "3.2"
```

Not all the data is going through. Only the header. I want to send the string as a file.xml that is all I have to do. any ideas of an easier way of doing this? or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the **$XMLString** to a XML view... I can't see the need for the Xml::build

Check this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html